# Emails are sent, but cron_schedule table is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

Magento ver 1.9.2.0

When trying to trouble shoot our custom magento cron task (it's not working)
I've realized that our cron_schedule table has not been updated since 2015.
[image: cron_schedule table]

Surprisingly all emails and other functionality is working like expected.

When emptying the table, new tasks are not adding. Neither from crontab tasks, (tried :

```
/bin/sh /chroot/home/domainname.com/html/cron.sh
```

and

```
/usr/bin/php /chroot/home/domainname.com/html/cron.php
```

Not from direct browser domainname.com/cron.php call.

However if i change the cron.php from default magento 1.9.2.0

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
            $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            exit;
        }
    }

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

to

this one (provided by follow developer)

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```

it populates the cron_schedule table.

What can be the issue? I would prefer to use default magento cron.php file and find the reason it's not working correctly. (and hope it can help find the reason our custom task it not working)

Comment: Can you give name of hosting provider ?

Answer (score 0):

Check     app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php  File

at line number 407

```
if (($this->hasQueue()) && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)
```

put this line

All Works Fine